# What does "ultimately vanishing" mean? (Needham)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, infinitesimals

In the Prologue of the book *Visual Differential Geometry and Forms* by Needham the notion of two functions $A(\epsilon)$ and $B(\epsilon)$ being **ultimately equal** is defined: it means that
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{A(\epsilon)}{B(\epsilon)} = 1.
$$
This is all good and seems to be motivated by how Newton used limits. But then a few lines below, Needham uses the notion **ultimately vanishing** without giving a definition. I just don't know what precisely this means. I first thought it may mean that $A(\epsilon)$ is ultimately equal to $\epsilon$, but then $\epsilon^2$ would not be ultimately vanishing, which doesn't look right. Being ultimately equal to the zero function also doesn't work. Can someone please tell me what this means?

Comment: "ultimately vanishing" is what we all should expect some day.

Comment: Why does ultimately equal to 0 not work?

Comment: @KevinCasto ... Ultimately equal to $0$ would mean $\lim_{ϵ → 0} \frac{A(ϵ)}{0} = 1$

Comment: Oh fair enough, I guess what I really meant was $\lim A(\epsilon) = 0$

Comment: Well, that could be a definition: any function which is ultimately equal to a function with lim A(ϵ) = 0. !?

Comment: Note that [that](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1102461) (i.e., $\exists B,\,\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} (B(\epsilon), A(\epsilon)/B(\epsilon)) = (0, 0)$) is the same as requiring that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} A(\epsilon) = 0$, as @KevinCasto [suggested](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1102394). \\ As a TeX matter, please use TeX instead of Unicode when possible; $\epsilon^2$ `\epsilon^2` and $²$ `²` look slightly different, and mathematicians are used to the former.

Comment: [Answer and meta thread](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5425/159957)

Comment: @LSpice If you can tell what he or she is trying to say, who cares what mathematicians are used to? Isn't this like telling people not to converse in their native tongue while in a foreign country i.e. "this is England, speak English, dammit!" ?

Comment: @LSpice : I suspect most mathematicians are more accustomed to $\varepsilon$ than to $\epsilon.$ I prefer the former since the latter looks too much like $\in. \qquad$

Comment: @LSpice Thus I would write $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0} (B(\varepsilon, A(\varepsilon) / B(\varepsilon)) $ rather than $\lim_{\epsilon\to0} (B(\epsilon, A(\epsilon) / B(\epsilon)). \qquad $

Comment: @HarryWilson, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1102825), "this is MathOverflow, it's best to speak TeX!" is consistent with the community position as I understand it. Askers (including me!) should care what mathematicians are used to because posting a question here is asking for the time of many expert mathematicians, and it is reasonable when you ask for someone's time to make it as easy as possible for them to do what you are asking (in this case, read and understand your question). But it was mainly a request and friendly advice for better reception, and not at all an order.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1102827), at the risk of being too chatty, I too prefer $\varepsilon$, but I try to restrict my unsolicited advice to hopefully reasonably objective matters of MO and TeX norms and semantics (e.g., $\epsilon$ for a small quantity is OK but $\in$ definitely isn't), and to avoid imposing subjective preferences such as $\epsilon$ vs. $\varepsilon$ even if, as here, I think that they are fairly widely agreed upon.

Comment: @LSpice: I was suspecting that $B(\epsilon)$ being ultimately equal to a function with $\lim A(\epsilon) = 0$ already implies that $\lim B(\epsilon) = 0$ as well. But how do you prove this? I'm probably blind.

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational: I was neither down nor upvoting. Everything you said in your linked deleted post is correct (it's just asymptotic analysis and I don't know why Needham is making such a fuzz out of it). But you didn't address my question. I said "ultimatey equal" is all good (it's well-defined). My problem was "ultimately vanishing" and you didn't address this. Hope this helps.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428580/what-does-ultimately-vanishing-mean-needham#comment1102860_428580), I think you accidentally made the same comment thrice.  Assuming all divisions are OK, if $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} A(\epsilon) = 0$ and $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} B(\epsilon)/A(\epsilon) = 1$, then $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} B(\epsilon) = \bigl(\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} B(\epsilon)\bigr)\bigl(\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} A(\epsilon)/B(\epsilon)\bigr)$ equals $0\cdot1 = 0$.

Comment: @LSpice: Damn that was too easy, cheers. (You need to flip one of the fractions, typo I guess)

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428580/what-does-ultimately-vanishing-mean-needham#comment1102870_428580), embarrassingly many typos, yes, but with hopefully obvious corrections.

Answer (score 4):

Since on page 275 Needham refers to Newton for the notion of an "ultimately vanishing" quantity, I would interpret that in the sense of Newton, where an ultimately vanishing quantity is an infinitesimal: $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}A(\epsilon )=0$. If "ultimately equal" is interpreted in the sense of Newton, it would mean two quantities $A$ and $B$ differ by an infinitesimal, $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}A(\epsilon)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}B(\epsilon)$ so an ultimately vanishing quantity is ultimately equal to 0 in Newton's sense.

See [Fleuriot's book](https://books.google.nl/books?id=wijrBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA76) on Newton's Principia for these two concepts.

---

Following the discussion in the comments, let me quote from Newton's [Principia](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Mathematical_Principles_of_Natural_Philosophy_(1846)/BookI-I) (book 1, section 1, lemma 1):

> Quantities, and the ratios of quantities, which in any finite time
> converge continually to equality, and before the end of that time
> approach nearer the one to the other than by any given difference,
> become ultimately equal.

So apparently Newton allows for both definitions of "ultimately equal", the one used by Needham (ratio tends to unity) and the alternative definition (difference tends to zero). "Ultimately vanishing" refers to "ultimately equal to zero" in the second sense, and I presume Needham follows that meaning.

I should add that the two definitions of ultimately equal ($A-B\rightarrow 0$ versus $A/B\rightarrow 1$) are equivalent for quantities which remain bounded when $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$. This may well be why Newton did not bother to distinguish the two.

Comment: the only point I want to make is that there is a certain inconsistency in the way Needham introduces "ultimately equal" and "ultimately vanishing"; a consistent definition in the sense of Newton would be to compare the difference rather than the ratio of two quantities; then "ultimately vanishing" means "ultimately equal to zero";

Comment: I'm not convinced: You seem to equate "ultimately equal" (as defined in my question) to having equal limit. But this is not true: take $1/\epsilon + 1$ and $1/\epsilon$. These functions have constant difference 1 but still they are ultimately equal!

Comment: certainly, $1/\epsilon +1 $ and $1/\epsilon$ are "ultimately equal" in the sense of Needham, but not in the sense of Newton, and I propose that what Needham means with "ultimately vanishing" is "ultimately equal to zero" _in the sense of Newton._

Comment: Ugh, I thought that the whole point Needham was making was that we should use the concept of limits (and being "ultimately equal") from Newton. So what on earth is he doing there?!

Comment: I was browsing through the paper "Newton and the Notion of Limit" by Pourciau (you can find in using Google) and I was pretty convinced that what Needham defines as "ultimately equal" is what Newton was using! Sorry, I'm not a historian, just a research mathematician trying to get the notions right.

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer! Maybe this resolves the confusion. But I wish Needham had clarified that! (I can live with his "proved beyond reasonable doubt" but not at this stage). @Beautifullyirrational: Please stop hijacking my post. Carlo Beenakker made a good point.

Comment: I have a question for you, "proved beyond reasonable doubt" and the principia as reference was mentioned in the same prologue you were reading (also the ultimate equality laws) **word to word**. So, what new information did you gain from the post  ? . Finally excuse me for "hijacking" your post by placing two comments where I mention the existence of a meta post.